# "Error Occured" message when clicked on Verfication link sent by Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhKMz.png)

I am working on a flutter project, and when i try to send a verification email, Firebase sents it .
, i receive the email on my registered user's mail box and when i click that verification link it says "error occured" as shown in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD5vP.png)

Help me solve this error

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.